# Loading dropdown based on another drop down

Tags: asp.net

I am Having two dropdowns. based on the selection of one the other dropdown must be filled. Using Ajax is one way but some times it takes time to load the second dropdown.

How to avoid this ?

Is any thing like i pull all the data and do all manipulations at client side and shown instead using server resource and ajax ?

Comment: How much data are you talking about? Have you thought about fixing your query? Basically, why would it be so slow to populate a dropdown? This should be quick.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload several hidden dropdowns and then display the appropriate one when the first dropdown is selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can preload all the values (assuming they are not too many, say <1000) and then populate the second dropdown with a script, not hitting the server again.